# css menu bar not flush

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to make the menu bar for my website flush against the top and side of the pages. Right now there is a slight gap at the top as well as on the left and right. I can't figure out what in my code is not allowing it to become flush. Here is what I have in my CSS. My Unorder list would basically be the Nav bar and the elements in the list (ul li) are the sections i.e Home About Us etc..

```
ul{
  padding:0;
  top:0;
  height:60px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  float:left;
  width:335px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:black;
  opacity:.6;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, try to add:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And if you have a heading (`h1`, `h1`, etc.) inside of the menu bar, then give that heading:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Both the `body` element and the `h1` - `h6` elements by default have margins in most browsers.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ul{
    padding:0;
    top:0;
    height:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
} 

body{
    margin-top:60px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body` has a default margin in most browsers. To reset it, use this CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```